# How to extract specific number in a string surrounded by numbers and text C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract specific number in a string with a format of "Q23-00000012-A14" I only wanted to get the numbers in 8 digit 00000000 the 12.

```
string rx = "Q23-00000012-A14"
string numb = Regex.Replace(rx, @"\D", "");
txtResult.Text = numb;
```

But im getting the result of 230000001214, I only want to get the 12 and disregard the rest. Can someone guide me.

Comment: If you are doing this for multiple similar strings, what are the commonalities?

Comment: Do the digits always start in the 5th place? Or after the first `-`? Are they always 8 digits?

Comment: @Charleh Im trying to create an id system with Q23 and A14 as a constant i need to get the 12 and add 1 as increment for the next ID or employee to add.

Comment: @doctorlove yes they are always 8 digit from 00000001 to 99999999

Comment: Could you refactor the code so you get a number instead of this string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your string are always in this format (numbers are covered with "-"), I suggest useing string.split()

```
 string rx = "Q23-00000012-A14"
 string numb = int.parse(rx.Split('-')[1]).ToString();//this will get 12 for you

 txtResult.Text = numb;
```

It's an easier way than using regex

Edit!! When you use rx.split('-') , it break string into array of strings with value of splited texts before and after '-'

So in this case:

rx.Split('-')[0]= "Q23"

rx.Split('-')[1]= "00000012"

rx.Split('-')[2]= "A12"

Comment: thanks a lot ill try is it possible to get the 12 ? how about my id becomes 123?

Comment: @GeorgeofJungle Edited. This should get you the number without 0s in front.if the number is 00000123 or 00012345 it will still works because this method clear out the zeroes

Comment: THank you i bit confuse using regex but your solution is more simple and I get what I wanted thank you so much.

Comment: whats the purpose of index [1]? in int.parse(rx.Split('-')[1]) ?

Comment: @GeorgeofJungle When you split by '-' , it break string into array of strings. I will edit this now

Answer (score 4):

So you shouldn't use Replace. Use [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
string pattern = @"[A-Z]\d+-(\d+)-[A-Z]\d+" ; 

var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var match = regex.Match("Q23-00000012-A14");
if (match.Success)
{
     String eightNumberString = match.Groups[1].Value;  // Contains "00000012" 
     int yourvalueAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(eightNumberString) ; // Contains 12
}
```

Comment: "\d{8}" is much simpler tho.. :p

Comment: @GeorgeofJungle :  There was a mistake. Just remove the `[`and the `]` on pattern string.

Comment: if my id becomes 123 or 2054? do i need to remove the \d?

Comment: @GeorgeofJungle : If it's still a eight digit number like 00000123 or 00002054 it will always working.

Comment: To allow any count of numbers you can use `@"-(\d+)-"`. `match.Groups[1].Value` will get the numeric value between the first two `-`. Poomrokc's non Regex solution is even better again tho, just split it off on `-`.

Comment: @Ksv3n i tried your solution above but im not getting any output anyway thank you so much.

Comment: I prepare Regex than split Can you edit your post above @Ksv3n

Comment: @GeorgeofJungle : I made the edit according to modiX

Comment: @Ksv3n thou i be using Poomrokc's  solution but ill try the regex thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Why you use don't simply substring or split function ?

```
string rx = "Q23-00000012-A14";

// substring
int numb = int.Parse(rx.Substring(5, 8));

// or split
int numb = int.Parse(rx.Split('-')[1]);


txtResult.Text = numb.ToString();
```

(I think it's a better way to use split method because if you change your constant 'Q23' length the method still work)

Comment: Thank you so much I already tried Poomrokc The 3years solution and it works